# Execute Project with dependencies to another local project in Maven

Tags: maven

I have the following project structure:

```
-parent (<packaging>pom</packaging>)
 |
 |--project 1(jar)
 |
 |--project 2 (jar, depends on project 1)
 |
 |--project 3 (jar, depends on project 1)
```

Questions:

1. How to execute a class in project 2? `mvn exec:java` from which project?
2. If I want to compile/package only project2, how do I do that? (If I do `mvn clean package` from project2, it does not find project1). I would like to do this without installing project1 before.

Of course the structure of the projects can be changed, if needed.

---

Below are shown relevant parts from pom.xml files.
parent/pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>parent: the parent project</name>
    <groupId>com.domain</groupId>

    <modules>
        <module>project1</module>
        <module>project2</module>
        <module>project3</module>
    </modules>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.domain</groupId>
            <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
            <version>${version.releaseVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.domain</groupId>
            <artifactId>project2</artifactId>
            <version>${version.releaseVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.domain</groupId>
            <artifactId>project3</artifactId>
            <version>${version.releaseVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
//other plugins defined in the <build> tag are not shown here
</project>
```

parent/project1/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.domain</groupId>
        <version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Project1: common classes</name>

</project>
```

parent/project2/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.domain</groupId>
        <version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>project2</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Project2: JMS gateway</name>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.domain</groupId>
            <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>project2-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.domain.jmsgateway.Demon</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

parent/project3/pom.xml is simmilar with project2

Comment: Re 2.: Please supply the relevant sections of your `parent,` `project1,` `project2` POMs.

Comment: @GeroldBroser Added the relevant sections.

Answer (score 0):

Re 1.: *"How to execute a class in project 2?"*

Maven is a *build* tool. Your `main` classes aren't executed automatically by default. Executing your `main` classes is supposed to be configured by assigning/binding appropriate Maven plugin(s) to the default lifecycle's `integration-test` phase or completely outside Maven after building - depending on your project.

Your `test` classes are executed (by the [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), by default) if you invoke `mvn` with the default lifecycle's `test` phase or one of those further in the chain described in the [Lifecycle Reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

#### EDIT:

Re 2. *"I would like to do this without installing project1 before."*

How is Maven supposed to resolve `p1` when building `p2` if you didn't, at least, install `p1` in advance? See [Maven Dependency Resolution – A Repository Perspective](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/12/maven-dependency-resolution-a-repository-perspective/):

> *When Maven resolves a dependency from a repository, these are the basic steps it follows:*
>
> *1. If the scope of this dependency is system, simply resolve it from local file system.*
>
> *2. Try to find the dependency **from local repository**, resolve it if it’s found.*
>
> *3. to 8.* [include remote repositories]

Comment: It is clear that they are not executed automatically, but `project2` is a demon that listens on a certain port, and I want to execute exactly one main class. If I do `mvn integration-test` on the level of the `parent`, it will integration-test everything (execute every exec plugin that is attached on that phase). If I do `mvn integration-test` in project2, it will complain, it misses prj1. Please correct if I am wrong here: it does not matter how a plugin is executed (either on a certain phase or directly), if it fails when called directly, it will fail also when called during a phase.